# DynamoDB streams AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER seems to be broken

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-streams

When I fetch records from DynamoDB streams using AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER for my shard iterator, passing in sequence number 212345200000000000573152750, I get 2 records for a particular shard (this is after 25 repeated calls to getRecords using nextShardIterator, to make sure I've fetched all records).

The sequence number for the two records are:

```
212345200000000000573864865
212345300000000000579344274
```

Both of these are greater than the requested sequence number.

If I repeat the same test, changing AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER to AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, I only get one record (212345200000000000573864865 is missing).

This makes no sense to me, since the missing record's sequence number is not equal to the requested sequence number when getting a shard iterator, so it seems like AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER and AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER should return the same 2 records.

I don't feel like I'm doing anything wrong, is DynamoDB streams simply broken?